# How can I use .htaccess rewrite to redirect the root URL to a subdirectory, but also have a fallback when nothing is found?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to find a solution for changing root to default to subdirectory_1, but when where is no file/directory inside `subdirectory_1`, redirect all request to `root` directory.

Folders

```
.
├── /subdirectory_1
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── about.html
│   └── ...
├── index.php
└── ...
```

For me main goal is to have Static Generated Site in `subdirectory_1`, but also have CMS (like Wordpress) on `root` (as admin for some posts, later to use with API).

**Example** of what I am looking for:

If I call `mysite.com/about` it opens file from `/subdirectory_1/about.html` and shows in URL `mysite.com/about` (*without `subdirectory_1`*).

But if I call `mysite.com/contacts` and there is no `contacts` file (or directory) in `/subdirectory_1` it should try to open `/contacts` in `root` directory

So far what have I found and tried is this in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTP redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/$1 [R,L,NC]

# ROOT Transfer to subdirectory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory_1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory_1/$1 [L]

# Redirects index (/) to subdirectory index first
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory_1/index.html [L]

# Wordpress config
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

It works almost fine, but there are some weird behauvour sometimes, when I access some file it shows whole URL with `subdirectory_1`. For example, I call `mysite.com/about` and it opens `mysite.com/subdirectory_1/about`, and if I try right away again `mysite.com/about` it opens as it should `mysite.com/about`.

Somehow it's not consistant :/

Maybe there is a better, cleaner and more reliable solution? Or I just made a mistake somewhere in .htaccess?

Comment: This sounds as if you have old, faulty redirects cached by your browser already ... Clear your history, or try in a private tab, and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: @CBroe I keeep in mind caching so  always was clearing all data, but I found that problem was with the trailing slash. My previous configuration didn't address the problem for it and it was redirecting to subfolder and including full subdirectory's name when there was no trailing slash at the end of adress. New edit solved that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in one of the programmers' Discord, I finally find a working **solution**. So I decided to share it with everyone.

My new .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/$1 [R,L,NC]

# Exceptions
# For all Wordpress Admin related links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(wp-admin|wp-login)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# ensure that all directory requests include a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]

# Make /subdirectory_1 like it was root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subdirectory_1/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory_1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory_1/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Wordpress config
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Now static generated website (in `subdirectory_1`) works correctly and I still can access WordPress.